# Automatically realign partitions from script in command line

Tags: android

I'm working on a really really wierd project.  I'm using Ubuntu to recover an Android device.  I'm doing this by launching Ubuntu and then using the GUI to keep the user informed.

I need to figure out a way to realign the partition tables.   When using parted -l print, parted shows that there are problems on the disk and asks for user input to correct the partition table endings. Is there another tool that I can use for a scripted recovery?

Basically, The partition tables at this point are correct, but the disk is in an unknown state.  I need to figure out a way to rewrite the partition table endings on the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parted has a script mode.

-s, --script
              never prompts for user intervention

Comment: does that automatically realign partitions?

Comment: No, you would have to write the 'script' to do it. I thought that was what you were looking for. Could be a fun (but be careful) exercise in bash scripting.

Comment: Well, parted print gives the option to fix automatically.  You have to press Y.